# NodeJS : Download File from Webcam -> not readable file

Tags: node.js, esp32, imagedownload

I've made a webcam with an ESP32 and a running Webserver on it. I can call the URL in my Browser and the image is displayed correct.

Now i want to download it with nodejs and http, and i have huge problems saving the image:
Here is my nodejs code

```
public SaveEntry(req: Request, res: Response) {
    get('http://192.168.179.1/capture', response => {
        let data;
        response.on('data', chunk => {
            data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            let config = {
                endPoint: process.env.MINIO_ADRESS,
                port: Number.parseInt(process.env.MINIO_PORT),
                useSSL: false,
                accessKey: process.env.MINIO_ACCESS,
                secretKey: process.env.MINIO_SECRET
            };
            writeFileSync('a.jpg',data);
            res.status(200).send();
           /*  console.log(data);
            var minioClient = new Client(config);
            console.log(typeof data);
            let buf = Buffer.from(data);
            minioClient.putObject('images', 'myImage1.jpeg', buf, (putErr) => {
                if (putErr) {
                    console.error(putErr);
                    res.send(putErr);
                }
                res.status(200).send();
            }); */
        });
    })
}
```

When i open the File, the image is not readable (The File Format is not supported)
Any ideas ?

Comment: What happens if you try to download from the command line using `curl` or `wget`?

Comment: @romkey Wget downloads the file and i can open it with any image software